# standard ml datatype function

Tags: function, types, union, sml, ml

I made a datatype of type number that can be either an int or real, and I need to make a function that adds the 2 numbers of type "number", and what I'm having problem with is with the syntax of defining such a syntax, I tried the following but none seems to work.
The code I wrote are the following, the following codes are written like this to check that the function recognizes n to be of type number:

```
fun plus n:number = "type number";

fun plus n:I = "type int of number";

fun plus n:number.I = "type int of number";
```

But none seem to work, is the syntax I'm writing in is correct or is it wrong?
Thanks

the datatype number i write is:

```
datatype number = 
  I of int
| F of real;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pattern match against your value constructors `I` and `F`, and do whatever is appropriate

```
fun plus (I a) (I b) = I (a+b)
  | plus (I a) (F b) = ...
  | etc...
```

This gives you 4 cases. You can of course also do it with only 2 cases, if you make a small helper function that unpacks a `number` to a `real`, to encompass all but the `int`-`int` case.